# ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

My error page tells me "param is missing or the value is empty: user" and references my user_params private method and my create action as the culprits. It also shows that all the params I'm passing in are getting picked up by the create post.

abbreviated Controller:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
  end
```

My form_tag that initiates the create post:

```
= form_tag @user do
  .form-group
    = label_tag :first_name, nil, class: 'col-md-2'
    = text_field_tag :first_name, nil, class: 'col-md-3'
    %br
  .form-group
    = label_tag :last_name, nil, class: 'col-md-2'
    = text_field_tag :last_name, nil, class: 'col-md-3'
    %br
  .form-group
    = label_tag :email, nil, class: 'col-md-2'
    = email_field_tag :email, nil, class: 'col-md-3'
    %br
  .actions.form-group
    = submit_tag 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary col-md-offset-2'
```

Comment: while @BroiSatse gives a solution, the reason is the params you receive are not nested in a `:user` hash, ie `params[:user]` is empty. Because in the html, your input names are not like `user[email]` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
= form_tag @user do
```

to

```
= form_for @user do |f|
```

And then all `label_tag` to `f.label`, `text_field_tag` to `f.text_field`, `email_field_tag` to `f.email_field` and finally `submit_tag` to `f.submit`. Remove all nils and all should work.

Comment: The error doesn't show up anymore, but the params are missing now. Kinda ironic :) Is there a reason to use form_for over form_tag?

Comment: `form_for` binds the object with fields and also provides better naming for the fields, so the params appear to be grouped on submission. With form tag all the params are being send as a separate param (no wrapping key is present)