# ActionController::ParameterMissing in ArticlesController#search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

help please
I'm writing my ROR blog and receive error "param is missing or the value is empty: article".

```
(Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:55:in `article_params'
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:31:in `search')
```

Here is my search method and private method:

```
def search
    if article_params[:search].blank?
      @articles = Article.all
    else
      @articles = Article.search(params)
    end
  end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

Also after this topic [ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737978/actioncontrollerparametermissing-in-userscontrollercreate) I changed peace of my partial from:

```
        <div class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <%= form_tag search_articles_path, method: :get do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control mr-sm-2" %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-light my-2 my-sm-0" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

to:

```
<div class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
  <%= form_for @article, search_articles_path, method: :get do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :search, placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control mr-sm-2" %>
    <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-light my-2 my-sm-0" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to permit the search param but also call the method

```
def search
  if article_params[:search].blank?
    @articles = Article.all
  else
    @articles = Article.search(article_params)
  end
end


def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :search)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, error disappeared, but "Search" function doesn't work, after click on button - just fast reloading and no errors in console

Comment: @OrkoElvis you asked why you were getting an error, not "how do I make search work in rails".  If you want help with that, we need to see more of the code, but it should be a different question.